# WooCommerce API : Create a Product Category

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

I am trying to create a product category using the WooCommerce API but failing to find the correct method.
I found this 
WC_API_Products::create_product_category
but, despite enabling the legacy API in the wp_admin side, I do not seem to have access to the WC_API_Products class.
Once I can programatically create categories, I can then look at using the api to add my products to these via code.
Thanks